# Powershell - query non-standard group members in an OU?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, query, groups, organizational-unit

I am looking to create a script which will only show users in an OU who are members of "non-standard" groups.

For example, all users in the "Accounting" OU will be members of at least one group with "Accounting" in its name. Example: "XYZ-Accounting-Global". This is our standard group naming. Those users with only "Accounting" group memberships can be skipped.

I would like to target only those users in the OU which are members of any non-standard group for that OU.

- Example: User is in the "Accounting" OU, and is a member of "XYZ-Accounting-Global", BUT is also a member of "XYZ-Payroll-Global".

So far, I have come up with this:

```
$domain = "DC=company,DC=com"

$dept = read-host "What is the DEPT. name?"

Get-ADuser -SearchBase "OU=$dept,OU=Users,OU=company,$domain" -Filter * -properties memberof | Where-Object {!($_.memberof -like "*$dept*")}
```

This isn't working correctly though. It seems to be returning those users who are not members of a group with the `$dept` name in it. Unfortunately, I do not know how to fix this.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to be returning those users who are not members of a group
>   with the $dept name in it

This is certainly because of the `!` you use in your `Where-Object` filter, which means `not`.

Try removing the exclamation mark :

```
Where-Object {($_.memberof -like "*$dept*")}
```

---

**Edit**

Regarding your comment, you could try :

```
Where-Object {($_.memberof -notlike "*$dept*")}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I had tried removing the "!" before, but when I do that, it returns ALL of the user objects in the OU. I'm really just trying to return those users with group memberships that do NOT contain the name of their dept ($dept).

Comment: @user201727 Ok, i've posted an Edit

Comment: Thanks again, but it still shows all user objects in the OU. Perhaps it is not possible for Powershell to do what I need it to do. My numerous Google searches on this have not come up with anyone who is trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @user201727 I am sure this can be done with PowerShell. The fact is that you are not clear enough about your OU/Groups/Users architecture. Please be more precise : print-screen or text Treeview